# Problem with "Element no longer valid" in Selenium-Python-IE 11

Tags: python, selenium, click, wait

When the web page is loaded, i have to click in a hyperlink. This click some times works, and sometimes don't. When this click is not working, i receive this issue:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

This is the most recurrent issue.

In another times, error executing javascript and Command line for the IE driver has stopped working (Close the program)

This is the html code that i must click

```
<div class="body">
    <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li class="nav-header">
            PAGOS
        </li>
        <li>
            <a tabindex="-1" href="../../inputNewOutgoing">
                 <span>Crear Pago Saliente</span> 
            </a>
        </li>
...
```

this is my python code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,'Crear Pago Saliente'))).click();
```

Also, I've tried with this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sidebar']/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).click()
```

What's wrong with this? I have to add more waits or try with another kind of wait?

Comment: Can you provide your url to replicatee this issue ? have you tried same on another browser ?

Comment: i'm testing only in IE (official browser in my job), so, i can't give you the url, because belong to a localhost

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException is occurs when your element is not attahced to DOM , if you increase wait time then hopefully wit will work or else use javascript and wait for page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stale Element Reference Exception is caused as your element is not attached to the DOM.
Many times waiting can be a solution to this problem, but the best solution is to **reinitialize the element in the catch block**.

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id='sidebar']/ul/li[2]/a/span')
    element.click()
except StaleElementReferenceException as error:
    print(error)
    print('The stale element reference occurred')
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id='sidebar']/ul/li[2]/a/span')
    element.click()
```

Comment: which library ia have to use for this: except StaleElementReferenceException as error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this code:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='sidebar']/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).click()
except StaleElementReferenceException as Exception:
    print('StaleElementReferenceException while trying to click the hyperlink, trying to click again')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='sidebar']/ul/li[2]/a/span"))).click()
```